# Big query - pivoting data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This is the input table:

| id | created_at | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d4e9a2eb-9eb6-483e-8fbb-7268202fc7b3 | 2023-05-17T11:18:04.640Z | task.created |
| d4e9a2eb-9eb6-483e-8fbb-7268202fc7b3 | 2023-05-17T11:18:08.480Z | task.completed |
| d4e9a2eb-9eb6-483e-8fbb-7268202fc7b3 | 2023-05-17T11:18:08.480Z | task.deleted |

this is the output table:

| id | task.created | task.completed | task.deleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| d4e9a2eb-9eb6-483e-8fbb-7268202fc7b3 | 2023-05-17T11:18:04.640Z | 2023-05-17T11:18:08.480Z | 2023-05-17T11:18:08.480Z |

Comment: Hi - so what have you tried and what issue are you facing? Please update your question with the SQL you’ve managed to write so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [PIVOT operator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator):

```sql
SELECT * FROM input_table
PIVOT(MAX(created_at) FOR status IN ('task.created' as task_created, 'task.completed' as task_completed, 'task.deleted' as task_deleted))
```

which produces:

| id | task_created | task_completed | task_deleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| d4e9a2eb-9eb6-483e-8fbb-7268202fc7b3 | 2023-05-17T11:18:04.640Z | 2023-05-17T11:18:08.480Z | 2023-05-17T11:18:08.480Z |

Full example:

```sql
WITH
  input_table AS (
  SELECT
    'd4e9a2eb-9eb6-483e-8fbb-7268202fc7b3' AS id,
    '2023-05-17T11:18:04.640Z' AS created_at,
    'task.created' AS status
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'd4e9a2eb-9eb6-483e-8fbb-7268202fc7b3',
    '2023-05-17T11:18:08.480Z',
    'task.completed'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'd4e9a2eb-9eb6-483e-8fbb-7268202fc7b3',
    '2023-05-17T11:18:08.480Z',
    'task.deleted')
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM input_table) 
  PIVOT(MAX(created_at) FOR status IN ('task.created' as task_created, 'task.completed' as task_completed, 'task.deleted' as task_deleted))
```

I used **MAX** as an aggregate function. Make sure it fits your use case or use a different one otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the conditional aggregation :

```
select id, max(case when status = 'task.created' then created_at end) as created,
           max(case when status = 'task.completed' then created_at end) as completed,
           max(case when status = 'task.deleted' then created_at end) as deleted
from mytable
group by id
```